# How to fix 'modulenotfounderror' if it is working in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

its a strange problem to me. I developed a programm in pycharm, which is working well. If im going to start this program in the terminal or in general outside of pycharm, there happen a lot of ModuleNotFoundErrors. Why are the imports in pycharm correct, but outside of it wrong?

I tried to change the imports. For example i changed "from core.bot import Bot" to "from bot import Bot". Now it works in the terminal, but in pycharm the line of code is underlined redly.

Some import examples:

```
'''
from core.bot import Bot
'''

'''
from talib._ta_lib import BBANDS, SMA, MACD
from binance.BinanceKeys import BinanceKey1
from binance.client import Client
'''
```

[image: thats the folder structure]

Comment: What folder structure do you have and are you running it from? it sounds like you are running the terminal inside the `core` folder, or some sort, whereas PyCharm would be running from a higher level.

Comment: i thried different things. for example i runed the terminal out of core(like u said) or one folder above it. Also i changed the working directory from core to a folder above it. My project folder is "tradingbot" in this folder are "core" and "binance". Actual the working directory is tradingbot/core

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your folder and file structure in PyCharm? Very hard to diagnose this without seeing the structure. Your working directory probably needs to be tradingbot for it to be able to `import core` like that

Comment: i changed my working directory to core and changed the import to "from bot import Bot". now this import is marked as wrong. But i can run the code in pycharm without errors. But why is it marked as wrong?

Comment: I think you are confusing the script you are running with the packages. You either need to install the packages properly (with pip, etc.), or the packages should be otherwise in the path (directory running the script being the obvious place.) If you are running `BotLauncherTerminal.py`, that should probably be at the tradingbot level, which uses the core and binance packages.

Comment: I found a solution. I moved the file, which i have to start into the trading bot folder(outside core).

Comment: It could be because when you run the program in Pycharm, Pycharm automatically calls sys.path.extend() to your top level and module level directory. Then, when you try to run it in the terminal, python cant find the modules. You could make it a package, or add import sys, sys.path.extend(~YOUR FILE PATH) to the top of the module you want to run in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid such issues, you should mark in Pycharm the directory from which you will call your main script as you Sources Root.

To do so, right click on the folder on the Pycharm tree folder structure (Project tab), select `Mark Directory as -> Sources Root`. The folder will become blue in color. All your imports paths now start from this Root folder.

As seen from the discussion in the comments and how the fact of changing an import line was making the imports crash in Pycharm or in terminal, your issue was coming from a difference in which folder was considered as the root. By using the setting I explain, one can avoid such issues.